# nutch,solr and ubuntu server 12.04lts

Tags: 12.04, installation, solr

I use Ubuntu server 12.04lts and i would know what version of nutch and solr  can be compatible with it.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 4):

Nutch 1.5 and Solr 3.6.0 are compatible.

**HowTo:**

1) install jdk

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

2) Download and unpack Solr

```
sudo mkdir ~/tmp/solr
cd ~/tmp/solr
wget http://mirror.lividpenguin.com/pub/apache/lucene/solr/3.6.0/apache-solr-3.6.0.tgz
tar -xzvf apache-solr-3.6.0.tgz
*default jetty in solr, try to run java -jar start.jar* shutdown Ctrl-C
```

check `http://localhost:8983/solr`

3) Download and unpack Nutch

```
sudo mkdir ~/tmp/nutch
cd ~/tmp/nutch
wget  http://mirror.rmg.io/apache/nutch/1.5/apache-nutch-1.5-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzvf apache-nutch-1.5-bin.tar.gz
```

4) configure Nutch

```
chmod +x bin/nutch
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

add in conf/nutch-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
</property>
```

exit

```
mkdir -p urls
cd urls
touch seed.txt
nano seed.txt
```

add urls for crawling, for example

```
http://nutch.apache.org/
```

in conf/regex-urlfilter.txt and replace

```
# accept anything else
+.
```

with a regular expression matching the domain you wish to crawl. For example, if you wished to limit the crawl to the nutch.apache.org domain, the line should read:

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/
```

5) configure Solr

```
 ~/tmp/solr/apache-solr-3.6.0/example/solr/conf
schema.xml add the following

<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"
            positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"
                    splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"
                    protected="protwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>


<field name="digest" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="boost" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="segment" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="host" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="site" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="tstamp" type="text" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
<field name="url" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="anchor" type="text" stored="true" indexed="false" multiValued="true"/>

change <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey> to
<uniqueKey>url</uniqueKey> 

in solrconfig.xml add
<requestHandler name="/nutch" class="solr.SearchHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="defType">dismax</str>
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <float name="tie">0.01</float>
       <str name="qf">
         content^0.5 anchor^1.0 title^1.2
       </str>
       <str name="pf">
         content^0.5 anchor^1.5 title^1.2 site^1.5
       </str>
       <str name="fl">
       url
       </str>
       <int name="ps">100</int>
       <bool name="hl">true</bool>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
<str name="hl.fl">title url content</str>
<str name="f.title.hl.fragsize">0</str>
<str name="f.title.hl.alternateField">title</str>
<str name="f.url.hl.fragsize">0</str>
<str name="f.url.hl.alternateField">url</str>
<str name="f.content.hl.fragmenter">regex</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

6) run Nutch crawler and index in Solr (make sure Solr has started)

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5
```

check indexed files @ `http://localhost:8983/solr`

[Source](http://notebyxz.blogspot.nl/2012/09/install-apache-nutch-1.html)